# ¿Por qué diccionarios y tuplas llevan una coma (,) al final? en settings.py de Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Me encuentro aprendiendo **Python** y estoy haciendo un parcial con el framework **Django**, y al momento de modificar los datos de `settings.py`, me he encontrado que ya sea **`diccionarios`** y **`tuplas`** contienen una coma (**,**) al final y no logro comprender cual es su función.

---

*Diccionario dentro de `settings.py`*

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles', #<-- esta coma
]
```

*Tupla dentro de `settings.py`*

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),) #<-- esta coma
```

**Sin ella no puedo hacer un `migrate`**

---

- ¿Por qué no puedo prescindir de ella?
- He hecho `tuplas` y `diccionarios` sin ella al final pero nunca me ha dado un error de sintaxis ¿Por qué?
- ¿Qué función cumple estando al final de una tupla o diccionario?

---

Estoy trabajando con:

- Python 3.7.4
- Django 2.2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En general, se recomienda, como buena práctica, dejar la coma al final.

Lo siguiente:

```py
my_dict = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
}
```

Permite una serie de cosas:

- Si añades una nueva línea suele ser un problema habitual olvidarse la coma del elemento/linea anterior con lo que obtendrás un error indeseado que puede que salte o que pase inadvertido.
- En los *diffs* verás menos ruido ya que solo cambia una línea, en lugar de dos (la primera línea cambia al añadir la coma y la segunda es la línea nueva que introduces).

Puedes ver esto más detallado y desarrollado [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11597911).

En el caso del diccionario que muestras podrías omitir la coma sin problemas (pero no lo hagas). Para el caso de la tupla que muestras sí que es necesario que añadas la coma. Una tupla se define separando elementos con comas. Los paréntesis no son necesarios pero se añaden para hacerlo más legible. Si no pones esa coma a una tupla de un elemento no será una tupla. Lo siguiente:

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")) # Esto no es una tupla
```

es igual a

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

Si `STATIFILES_DIRS` está esperando una tupla lo anterior dará error.

En cambio, lo siguiente:

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
```

es equivalente a:

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),) # Los paréntesis añaden claridad
```

Comment: Gracias!, no tenía ni idea de que era buena práctica, habrá que aplicarlo entonces :)